# Why can't I connect to PLEX sever via my roku but I can via my tablet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, video-streaming

On my home LAN I can connect/play media stored on my PC via my tablets but am unable to even connect to it via my roku box?

I manually enter the IP address of my machine in the browser of my tablet to connect and it works fine (just to test it out). However, the server doesn't get detected when manually entering the IP of my machine on my roku box? I'm not sure I understand why this would be the case. I'm not sure I know where to look or how to resolve this?

Comment: Just to verify there aren't networking issues between those 2 devices, Are you able to ping your roku from your media server. Any firewalls to disable? I assume that auto detect fails on the roku? Does the roku need the 32400 port specified when inputting the IP? This article has some relevance : https://forums.plex.tv/index.php/topic/37215-frequently-asked-questions/#entry236661